# any application which could sync pics/videos on ubuntu with picasa web album?

Tags: photo-management, google-picasa

Since picasa is no longer available on ubuntu(and i dont want to go for the workarounds for installing it), is there some application available in Ubuntu which can sync albums with picasa web albums?

Answer (score 3):

For syncing your photos to Picasa instantly I would recommend Conduit, it's in the [Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/conduit).

More on Conduit [here](http://live.gnome.org/Conduit), at their Gnome.org page.

Comment: Does this do proper two-way sync to Picasa Web Albums? It looks interesting.

Comment: @TomBrossman yes it does two way sync nicely [Picture](https://picasaweb.google.com/106813729925681106144/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCOOHw46F-fryngE#5709110428933204562)

Comment: Sweet. I can think of several uses for this already.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution that runs in the background and has full two way-sync, and works for very large collections you may want to check out:

https://github.com/leocrawford/picasawebsync

(full disclosure, I wrote it)